# Java program returns error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, arrays

Why does this program return `error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String` ?

```
public class StringConcatenation{
    
    public static void main(String []args){
        int[] testing = {0,1,3,4,5,6};
        String mark = "";
        for(int i=0;i<testing.length;i++)
        {
            // mark += testing[i]; But this line works fine
            mark = testing[i]; /* This line doesn't work */
        }
        System.out.println(mark);
     }
}
```

StringConcatenation.java:8: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String
mark = testing[i];

Comment: What do you feel += does in that context? What does the documentation say?

Comment: Neither of these examples work ...

Comment: of course. its part of a program. not the whole thing.  add to the beginning
    int[] testing = {0,1,3,4,5,6};
for example and then it should compile.

Comment: So you think you can do `String mark += testing[i];`? You may have `String mark = ...` and `mark += ...`, but certainly not the snippet you've posted.

Comment: apologies you are correct, String should be initialised to "" outside the loop. then it works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first way uses string concatenation, which is special cased in the Java language to allow you to use any object or primitive type.  However, you cannot just assign a random value to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

The + operator can handle a string and an integer, converting the integer to string before concatenating. But you can't assign an integer to a string. Has nothing to do with using an array.

Answer (score 0):

The operation += which translates to addition over its current value, converts integer to string and then concatenates it to the current state of string. However when you try to assign an integer value to a reference which is of type string, compiler will throw an error.

There are languages that will do even this for you, but it just does not work like that in a strongly typed language like java.